# Prove that $2n-3\leq 2^{n-2}$ , for all $n \geq 5$ by mathematical induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing, induction

### Prove that $2n-3\leq 2^{n-2}$ , for all $n \geq 5$ by mathematical induction

I have to prove by mathematical induction that: $2n-3\leq 2^{n-2}$ , for all $n \geq 5$

Thank you for the Review.

Comment: This statement is wrong

Comment: I've edited your post to take advantage of $\LaTeX$ formatting.  Please confirm that it still says what you intended...  (because I've transcribed pretty much exactly what was written, but, as Alex mentioned, this is pretty wrong)

Comment: the answer will be wrong for k=1 because they mentioned that the value to e substuted should be less than or equal to five but we had taken n=2 then k+1 will be wrong -hense proved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n=5$ you have
$$ 8=2^{5-2} \geq 2\cdot5-3 = 7$$
So the statement is *correct* for $n=5$

Now assume $2^{n-2} \geq 2n-3$ is valid for some fixed $n$ then for $n+1$ you will get:

$$2^{n-1} = 2^{n-2} + 2^{n-2} \geq 2^{n-2} +2 \stackrel{assumption}{\geq}2n-3+2 = 2(n+1)-3$$

Thus
$$2^{n-2} \geq 2n-3 \Longrightarrow 2^{n-1} \geq 2(n+1)-3$$
which means the statement is correct for every $n\geq5$

---

(Answer to previous question)

For $n=6$ you have 
$$2\cdot 6 = 12 < 2^{6-2} = 2^4 = 16$$

Thus your statement is wrong

---

> However, if you assume $2n\leq2^{n-2}$ for all $n\geq 6$ now you have:
>   $$2(n+1) = 2 +2n \stackrel{assumption}{\leq} 2 +2^{n-2} \leq 2^{n-2}+2^{n-2} = 2^{n-1} $$
>   Thus
>   $$2n\leq2^{n-2}\Longrightarrow 2(n+1)\leq2^{n-1}$$
>   So **this** statement is correct for all $n\geq6$.

Comment: Yes, probably it should be $2n \leq 2^{n-2}$ for all $n > 5$.

Comment: Yes, i´ve missed one part, in fact, it is: $2^{n-2} \geq 2n-3$ for all $n \geq 5$

Comment: I answered this question as well now.

Comment: finally the answer to the question you hopefully *really* had

Answer (score 1):

Another way: this is equivalent to showing that $n<2^{n-3}$ for $n \geq 6$. The base and assumption state are the same. The inductive step is 
$$
n+1 < 2n<2^{n+1-3}=2 \cdot 2^{n-3}
$$
Divide through $2$ and you are back to your assumption step, hence the statement is proven.